# Problema con el paginador, me muestra 2 paginas que no deberia

Tags: php

tengo un problema con el paginador y es que cuando llego a la pagina numero 6 me muestra la pagina 0, 1 cuando solo me deberia mostrar la pagina 2
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y cuando estoy en la pagina numero 7 me muestra la pagina 1 cuando deberia solo colocar la pagina 2
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ya cuando estoy en la pagina 8 si me muestra perfectamente como debe ser, lo que quiero es ver como hacer para que cuando este en la pagina 6, 7, 8, 9 etc (cuando haya mas registro que mostrar) se vean como en las demas paginas ejemplo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
que solo me muestra la pagina 2 y esta se deberia ir corriendo a medida de que vaya pasando de pagina lo que trato es que no me muestre toda las paginas de golpe solo algunas

```
<div class="paginador">
<ul>
    <?php if($pagina > 1) 
    { 
        ?>             
        <a data-title="Pagina anterior" href="?pagina=<?php echo $pagina - 1; ?>">&#10094;  &#10094;</a>
        <a href="?pagina=1">1</a>
            <li>...</li>
        <?php
    }
    if($pagina >= 5 && $pagina+5 <$total_paginas)
    {
        for($i = $pagina-5; $i <=$pagina+5; $i++)
        { 
            if($i == $pagina) echo '<li class=pgselect>'.$i.'</li>';
            else echo '<a href="?pagina='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>';                       
        }
            
    }
    else if($pagina <= 5)
    {
        for($i = ($pagina > 1) ? 2 : 1; $i <=$pagina+6; $i++)
        { 
            if($i >= $total_paginas)
                continue;

            if($i == $pagina) echo '<li class=pgselect>'.$i.'</li>';
            else echo '<a href="?pagina='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>';                       
        }
    } 
    else if($pagina >= $total_paginas-5) 
    {
        for($i = $pagina-6; $i <=($pagina == $total_paginas ? $total_paginas : $total_paginas-1) ; $i++)
        { 
            if($i == $pagina) echo '<li class=pgselect>'.$i.'</li>';
            else echo '<a href="?pagina='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>';
        }                
    }
    if($pagina != $total_paginas) 
    {
        ?>
        <li>...</li>
        <a href="?pagina=<?php echo $total_paginas; ?>"><?php echo ''.$total_paginas.''; ?></a>
        <a data-title="Siguiente pagina" href="?pagina=<?php echo $pagina + 1; ?>">&#10095; &#10095;</a>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

ayuda por favor

Comment: ¡Te enredas mucho con las condiciones! NO me da el laburo pa escribir código pa responderte, pero te sugiero que uses condiciones más simples; posiblemente estás cayendo en uno de los casos del if-elseif-elseif y no lo esperas porque son condiciones muy disímiles (`if gato elseif banano elseif brócoli`). Hazle seguimiento y verás

Comment: Entiendo muy poco sobre ese tema y hice solo el conocimiento que tenia no sabria como resolverlo

Comment: ayuda por favor :(

Answer (score 0):

Te propongo una solución un poco más compacta y fácil de mantener. Además, generalizada a cualquier rango de páginas y con longitud de ventana configurable:

```
<?php

$pag_ini=10;
$pag_fin=25;
$ventana=3;

if(!isset($_GET['pagina']))
    $_GET['pagina']=$pag_ini;

$p=$_GET['pagina'];

if($p-$ventana<=$pag_ini)
    $ventana=2*$ventana+$pag_ini-$p+1;
if($p+$ventana>=$pag_fin)
    $ventana=2*$ventana+$p-$pag_fin+1;

echo '<a href="?pagina='.$pag_ini.'">'.$pag_ini.'</a> ... ';
for($i=$p-$ventana;$i<=$p+$ventana;$i++){
    if($i>$pag_ini and $i<$pag_fin){
        if($p==$i) echo '_'.$i.'_ ';
        else echo '<a href="?pagina='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a> ';
    }
}
echo '... <a href="?pagina='.$pag_fin.'">'.$pag_fin.'</a> ';
```

Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios